# Allocating objects into elements of an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> There is an array of `N` items. Each of the array elements can house different number of objects in it. Now your task is to choose certain elements such that `P` objects are filled in them. We have to make sure that the elements in the array which are chosen are consecutive. The cost to choose any element in the array is `C` irrespective of their capacity.

> Design an algorithm in `O(n*log(n))` time complexity for determining the minimum cost element allocation. The allocated elements should be consecutive in the array and their capacities should sum to atleast `P`

Here my approach is pretty basic, where I intend to sort the array elements in decreasing size of their capacity. Post this, the rooms will be out on allocation and a left and right pointer will keep a track of the current range of rooms allocated. For each new element to be chosen, there will be a cost `C` being added to the total cost. Another variable will keep a track of the number of objects being allocated to the element. As soon as all the objects are allocated, the iteration should stop. Since we are having the maximum number of object capacity to the left, as the arrangement is descending in nature, we will get out left pointer to always point to the left.

Here the major computational capacity or the most time complex step is sorting and it should not take more than `O(n*log(n))` time, thus the capacity is met.

The pseudocode for the same is:

```
Sort(capacities) // O(n log(n))
minCost = infinity
currentSum = 0
left = 0

for right = 0 to n-1:
    currentSum += capacities[right]
    
    while currentSum >= P:
        minCost = min(minCost, (right - left + 1) * C)
        currentSum -= capacities[left]
        left++
        
minCost is the minimum cost of element allocation.
```

> Design an algorithm in O(n) time complexity for part (a) above.

I think it would be just to initialize left and right pointers both pointing to the beginning of the array. Initialize currentSum to track the sum of capacities within the current window.
Start a loop while the right pointer is within the bounds of the array.
Expand the window by moving the right pointer to the right and adding the capacity of the current element to currentSum until P is reached.
Now accordingly adjust the left and right pointer by moving to the right such that the number of objects being assigned to elements are P.
Calculate the cost using `(right - left + 1) * C`
Update the minimum cost if this cost is less than the current minimum. Continue the loop by moving the right pointer to the right.

Pseudocode for the same is:

```
minCost = infinity
currentSum = 0
left = 0

for right = 0 to n-1:
    currentSum += capacities[right]
    
    while currentSum >= P:
        minCost = min(minCost, (right - left + 1) * C)
        currentSum -= capacities[left]
        left++

minCost is the minimum cost of room allocation.
```

> Now suppose they don’t care about the cost and total capacity anymore. But they came up with a beauty criteria for an allocation. According to them, an allocation is beautiful if GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of capacities of all elements in the allocation is at least equal to or greater than a constant K. And they want to take maximum number of contiguous elements possible. Your task is to design an algorithm in `O(n*log(n))` time complexity for determining the maximum number of contiguous rooms they can get which satisfy the beauty constraints. You can assume access to a blackbox GCD algorithm which can give you GCD of two numbers in constant O(1) time.

I would need some help with this part where I'm unsure how would the GCD be involved here and how can we solve in `O(n*log(n))` time

**EDIT**

The exact question is:

P friends arrive at a hotel after a long journey and want rooms for a night. This hotel has n rooms linearly arranged in form of an array from left to right where array values depict the capacities of the rooms. As these are very close friends they will only consider consecutive rooms for staying. As you are the manager of the hotel you are required to find cheapest room allocation possible for them ( sum of the capacities of selected rooms should be greater than or equal to P ). Cost of booking every room is same and is equal to C.

(a) (5 points) Design an algorithm in `O(n*log(n))` time complexity for determining the minimum cost room allocation. The allocated rooms should be consecutive in the array and their capacities should sum to atleast P.

(b) (10 points) Design an algorithm in `O(n)` time complexity for part (a) above.

(c) (15 points) Now suppose they don’t care about the cost and total capacity anymore. But they came up with a beauty criteria for an allocation. According to them, an allocation is beautiful if GCD (Greatest Common Divisor) of capacities of all rooms in the allocation is at least equal to or greater than a constant K. And they want to take maximum number of contiguous rooms possible. Your task is to design an algorithm in `O(n*log(n))` time complexity for determining the maximum number of contiguous rooms they can get which satisfy the beauty constraints. You can assume access to a blackbox GCD algorithm which can give you GCD of two numbers in constant `O(1)` time.

(d) (10 points) Give proof of correctness and time complexity analysis of your approach for parts (a) and (b).

Comment: The assignment description is hard to read -- probably written by a non-English author. *"We also have to make sure that the elements in the array which are consecutive."*: what does this mean? That the **selected** elements in the array **are** consecutive? If so, how does sorting guarantee that? Sorting will make non-consecutive elements consecutive, and vice versa. I don't really understand this challenge.

Comment: @trincot i have edited the question. yes you got it right that the elements have to be consecutive. i thought if we sort them then the order changes completely and then it satisfies the `O(n*log(n))` condition and get the minimum cost in that case.

Comment: OK, does that mean that this question comes down to selecting the smallest (consecutive) subarray such that the sum of the capacities is at least P? Then I don't see why that should be O(n\*log(n)). A sliding window algorithm will find it in O(n). But maybe I misunderstand. Is the act of allocating something that happens during the algorithm? Is every *access* (read) of an array element an "allocation", or is it merely the size of the returned subarray?

Comment: @trincot sliding window is the way such that the cost is not mimnimised is what i can infer, but while arranging, i.e. sorting the cost is minimised further. let me add the exact question below in the edit.

Comment: OK, there I see that (b) is asking for a O(n) solution, which will be the sliding window algorithm. As something that is O(n) is also O(nlogn), it can be the answer for (a) too. If you really wanted to, you could use the sorting approach, but then you still need to identify which slice of rooms is *consecutive* in the *original* ordering.

Comment: So, I think your first solution (with sorting) is wrong.

Comment: @trincot the cost will be more for the O(n) sliding window than the one where we will be using the sorting technique. If we sort, this eventually changes the ordering and then we get a lower cost associated with it. Is this a viable possibility?

Comment: You'll only get lower costs for solutions that select non-consecutive rooms. True, they will be consecutive in the sorted order, but the question is to make a consecutive selection from the *original* array. If you would be allowed to shuffle the array *before* determining what is consecutive, there would be no use in specifying the "consecutive" constraint, as anything could be made to "look" consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for (a) of the original problem. For both (a) and (b) you can use two pointers, keeping track of the capacity between them ('cur_capacity'). I.e., if the capacity is too small, advance the forward pointer and increase cur_capacity by the capacity of the new room, otherwise advance the rear pointer and decrease the cur_capacity by the capacity of the room that just left our subarray. Keep track of the minimum length subarray where cur_capacity is good.

This is O(n) which is also O(n log n).

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. can you please help brainstorm for the GCD part?

Comment: It's better to have 1 S/O question per post. Move that to a different question and I or someone else will help soon.